# Creating a custom router in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9

How do you create a custom router for two related pages?

About us and person page. The URL structure would be like so `http://example.com/about-us/` and `http://example.com/about-us/john`. There will be multiple people, so the people's page URL can't be hardcoded i.e. `about-us/mike`, `about-us/jane`.

Comment: Why you don't create a cms page with a number of peaples that you want Since the content is different ?

Comment: Because the number of people might/will change. And the pages are created from records in the db @Prince

Answer (score 0):

you need to study below post for same

you need to create custom router for that

```
<default>
<web>
  <routers>
     <myextension_myrouter>
         <area>frontend</area>
         <class>Mynamespace_Myextension_Controller_Router</class>
     </myextension_myrouter>
 </routers>
</web>
```

More info:-
http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-router-in-magento/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/101871)

Comment: inchoo never change it's link

Comment: Links are good, but they should never be the only piece of information in your answer ! It was necessary to learn the SE policy before joining it .https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question. I already understand how to create a custom router, but not for this particular case. I've been reading the article, but most of it flies over my head. Thank you though.